# PHP XPATH within changing XML structure

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I've an XML file like this:

```
<tr class="station">  
  <td class="realtime"> 
    <span>
      15:11 
    </span>
  </td> 
</tr>

<tr class="station">  
  <td class="clock"> 
    15:20 
  </td> 
</tr>

<tr class="station">  
  <td class="clock"> 
    15:30 
  </td> 
</tr>

<tr class="station">  
  <td class="realtime"> 
    <span>
      15:41 
    </span>
  </td> 
</tr>
```

and I wanna parse it with xpath in php. The xml is been updated and parsed quite often.
I always want to get the first time (in this case 15:11)
The problem is that its not sure whether the surrounding tag is a td by class "clock" or "realtime".
If there is a so surrounding realtime, then there is a span tag within. Otherwise not.
In fact, its always the first "station"-class tag in which the information is, that matters. 
So is it possible to tell xpath to just evaluate within this tag?
Is there a good method for doing this in xpath?
(sry for my bad english)

Comment: There's no 15:11 in your sample? However, retrieving the first element would be trivial. If that's the complete snippet of HTML, just do `//td` for your xpath, which would return an array of all `<td>` elements, then retrieve the .innerTEXT of only the first entry in that array, which would be the very first 15:41 of your sample.

Comment: sry, ur right! the first "15:41" was meant to be "15:11". Corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In fact, its always the first
>   "station"-class tag in which the
>   information is, that matters. So is it
>   possible to tell xpath to just
>   evaluate within this tag?

With this wellformed input source:

```
<table>
    <tr class="station">
        <td class="realtime">
            <span>
                15:41
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station">
        <td class="clock">
            15:20
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station">
        <td class="clock">
            15:30
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station">
        <td class="realtime">
            <span>
                15:41
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This XPath expression:

```
/table/tr[@class='station'][1]/td
```

**Note**: Just select the element you want and use the proper DOM API method to get the **string value**. It doesn't matter whether there is a `span` element or not.

If you want to...

```
/table/tr[@class='station'][1]/td//text()
```